# Does Xamarin convert a Forms app to Java and if not then how does it run on Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Forms application and I'm confused about how it runs on iOS which I understand uses Swift and on Android which I think is Java.

Can anyone explain what happens to the C# code and how it's able to run that shared code on these two platforms?

Comment: Here is a document for reference.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/introduction-to-mobile-development#how-does-xamarin-work

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known misconception among the Xamarin community and other communities that Xamarin is a wrapper over the Java(Android) and Objective-C(iOS) but that is pretty much not true.

When you read the Microsoft documentation it says that,

**Under the Hood**

> On iOS: C# is ahead-of-time (AOT) compiled to ARM assembly language. The .NET framework is included, with unused classes being stripped out during linking to reduce the application size. Apple does not allow runtime code generation on iOS, so some language features are not available, Hence see [Xamarin.iOS Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations).
>
> On Android: C# is compiled to IL and packaged with MonoVM + JIT’ing. Unused classes in the framework are stripped out during linking. The application runs side-by-side with Java/ART (Android runtime) and interacts with the native types via JNI (see Xamarin.Android Limitations ).

The linker documentation for [Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows) and [Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) provides more information about this part of the compilation process.

Runtime 'compilation' – generating code dynamically with System.Reflection.Emit – should be avoided.

Apple’s kernel prevents dynamic code generation on iOS devices, therefore emitting code on-the-fly will not work in Xamarin.iOS. Likewise, the Dynamic Language Runtime features cannot be used with Xamarin tools.

Some reflection features do work (eg. MonoTouch.Dialog uses it for the Reflection API), just not code generation.

Good luck feel free to revert in case of queries

Answer (score 0):

> it runs on iOS which I understand uses Swift and on Android which I think is Java

You are oversimplifying the inner workings of these OSes. In the end, iOS is based on the Darwin kernel and Android on Linux. They can run anything as far as the device is concerned. Apple and Google provide fully-featured APIs in Swift and Java respectively to communicate with the low-level internals of the operating system. This does not prevent anyone from building their own SDK on top of those SDKs in different programming language like C#. You can also run C code on both platforms if you need the raw speed.

If you want more info on how this works (the internals are somewhat different between iOS and Android) here's a nice link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/understanding-the-xamarin-mobile-platform